# How connect to database and get data via python like in R

Tags: python, r

I new in python. I need connect to mysql database and get data. Before that, I easily took data via R using  `rodbs`like this.

```
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
db_user = 'k'
db_password = 'F6'
db_name = 'meg'
db_table = 'dat'
db_host = 'my.g2s' # for local access
db_port = 3306

# 3. Read data from db
mydbV7 = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = db_user, password = db_password,
                     dbname = db_name, host = db_host, port = db_port)
sV7 = paste0("select * from ", db_table)

rsV7 = dbSendQuery(mydbV7, sV7)

df =  fetch(rsV7, n = -1)
```

but when i tried to implement the same principle in python i get errors

```
import pyodbc

>>> db_user = 'k'
>>> db_password = 'F6'
>>> db_name = 'meg'
>>> db_table = 'dat'
>>> db_host = 'my.g2s' # for local access
>>> db_port = 3306
>>> mydbV7 = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = db_user, password = db_password,
...                      dbname = db_name, host = db_host, port = db_port)

 File "<stdin>", line 2
    ...                      dbname = db_name, host = db_host, port = db_port)
                             ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

How can i correct get data via python 3.9?
As always, I appreciate any of your help.

Comment: maybe in `dbConnect()` put all arguments in one line. OR write code in file and run `python script.py`

Comment: Python imports in different way. If you use `import pyodbc` then you have to use `pyodbc.dbConnect( dbConnect.MySQL(), ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As describe [in the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html), you can `import mysql.connector` and then use :

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'scott', 
                              password = 'password',
                              host = '127.0.0.1',
                              database = 'employees')
```

Of course, you have to change the values with yours.
`cnx` will then represent the connection with your database.

Comment: ,thank you , but how get data from table
("select * from ", db_table)

Comment: Everything is very well explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html). You first have to create a cursor using `cnx.cursor()` and then you can run your querry using `cursor.execute(my_query)`